# Creating a BSSPLINE IN R on a SAS system

Tags: r, sas

I am running R code in SAS and trying to create a bs spline

Here is the code I run:

```
K <- 1000
tgrid <- seq(0,cut,length=K)

dur <- function(i,j,knots){
  integrate(function(x) as.numeric(bs(x,knots=quantile(time[event==1],seq(0,1,length=hknots+2)[-c(1,hknots+2)]),
        degree=3,intercept=T, Bound = c(0,cut+0.0001))[,j]),0, tgrid[i], rel.tol=.Machine$double.eps^0.1)$value
}

hknots <- 2
(hknotsp <- quantile(time[event==1],seq(0,1,length=hknots+2)[-c(1,hknots+2)]))
t <- bs(time,knots=hknotsp,intercept=T, Bound=c(0,cut))

Tgrid <- mat.or.vec(K,hknots+4)

for (i in 1:K){
  for (j in 1:(hknots+4)){
    Tgrid[i,j] <- dur(i,j,hknots)
  }
print(i)
}

d <- t(sapply(1:n, function(x) Tgrid[which.min(abs(tgrid-time[x])),]))
dw <- d
```

I keep getting the error code :

WARNING: R: Error in is.finite(if (is.character(to)) to <- as.numeric(to) else to) :
WARNING: R:   default method not implemented for type 'closure'

Comment: Does this error occur if you run it in R directly (in which case this is just an `r` issue, I imagine), or is it only when you run it through the SAS interface (I assume you are running it via `PROC IML`?)